# Refer the Clicked element using $(this) when used in another function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

How do I refer the clicked element with `$(this)` when `$(this)` is used in function created outside or somewhere else other than in the click method. Following is the demo of the HTML mark up is use:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>some value...</td>
        <td>some value...</td>
        <td>some value...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some value...</td>
        <td>some value...</td>
        <td>some value...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some value...</td>
        <td>some value...</td>
        <td>some value...</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

In my jQuery I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var td = $('td');
    var count = 0;
    td.click(function () {
        if (count == 0) {
            //do this
        } else {
            //run this function
            demo();
        }
    })
})

function demo() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red'); // How do I refer to the clicked as $(this) here 
}
```

Comment: count is always 0 in your example currently...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bugs/Suggestions:**

1. You misspelled the `ready`
2. `count` is not incremented in your code snippet, so `else` will never executed(I've incremented it in below code)
3. Use `===` for comparing the `count` with `0`

You can pass the `$(this)` as parameter to the `demo()` function.

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var td = $('td');
  var count = 0;
  td.click(function() {
    if (count++ === 0) {
      //do this
    } else {
      // Send the context as parameter
      demo($(this));
    }
  });
})

function demo(el) {
  el.css('color', 'red');
  // el here is the `td` that is clicked
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some value...</td>
    <td>some value...</td>
    <td>some value...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some value...</td>
    <td>some value...</td>
    <td>some value...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some value...</td>
    <td>some value...</td>
    <td>some value...</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

You can also use `call()` or `apply()` to bind the `this` context to the `demo()` function and use it as `this` inside the `demo` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var td = $('td');
  var count = 0;
  td.click(function() {
    if (count++ === 0) {
      //do this
    } else {
      //run this function

      demo.call($(this));
      // Don't just call the function, also change the context to the passed context
    }
  });
})

function demo() {
  this.css('color', 'red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some value...</td>
    <td>some value...</td>
    <td>some value...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some value...</td>
    <td>some value...</td>
    <td>some value...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some value...</td>
    <td>some value...</td>
    <td>some value...</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value of `this` as an argument to `demo`.

Comment: It would be better if you shared the resulting code and explain your answer.

Comment: Sorry, i was answering from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I refer to the clicked  as $(this) here

The answer is: You shouldn't. You should pass the element into the function. If you *really* want to use `this` to refer to the DOM element, you need to use `call` or `apply` to specify a context for the `demo` function:

```
$(document).read(function(){
 var td = $('td');
 var count = 0;
 td.click(function() {
    demo.apply(this);
  })
})

function demo() {
 $(this).css('color', 'red'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just bind to the click event of the `td` element and if it doesn't exist the function will never fire:

```js
$('td').on('click', function(){
  // if you need to know how many tds you can do this:
  // var cellNum = $('td').length;
  // console.log(cellNum);

  turnRed($(this));
});

function turnRed(el){
  el.css({"background-color" : "red"});
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>some value...</td>
   <td>some value...</td>
   <td>some value...</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>some value...</td>
   <td>some value...</td>
   <td>some value...</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>some value...</td>
   <td>some value...</td>
   <td>some value...</td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

If there *are* other td's on the page that you don't want under consideration, you can use an id or class on your table to isolate the cells you're interested in (example):

```
$('table.sometableClass > td').on('click', function(){});
```